# Lifting property for Hausdorff spaces

Tags: general-topology, diagram-chasing

I was scrolling nlab instead of studying my topology final, and stumbled on the following page: https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/separation+axioms+in+terms+of+lifting+properties#hausdorff_spaces_

And intrigued, I tried to understand the lifting property for Hausdorff spaces. Which I understand as follows:

Denote by $*$ the singleton topological space, by 2 the indiscrete space on two points $\{0,1\}$ and by A the space whose set is $\{0,1,2\}$ and whose open sets are $\{\emptyset, \{0\}, \{1\}, \{0,1\}, \{0,1,2\}\}$. We have the following categorical definition of X being Hausdorff: X is hausdorff is and only if for all $f:2\to X$, which makes the square commute, there exists a diagonal morphism, such that the diagram commutes [image]

I am almost sure I misunderstood this, because I am assuming all arrows should be continuous, but taking the indiscrete on 2, means the function from 2 to A just isn't. Should I just take the discrete instead of the indiscrete on 2? but that isn't what the nlab is leading me to believe. Am I misunderstanding the category in which this diagram lies?

Comment: I think you meant your set to be $\{0,1,2\}$.

Comment: Also, your space $A$ isn't Hausdorff, so it should not satisfy that property anyway.

Comment: And I may be misunderstanding your question/notation because it is a bit unclear what role $A$ plays with respect to $X$.

Comment: @Randall Yup thanks I fixed it. The fact that A isn't Hausdorff is voluntary, its the way I interpreted the nLab page, though I may have misunderstood it. From reading that page, it seems that A play the role of choosing open sets to separate x and y, by taking preimages of the diagonal function

Comment: @DevVorb According to the help while editing a post, you can add an image by typing Ctrl-G and then cut and paste, or drag and drop, or browse on your computer.  It's not difficult.  (You would first have to convert your tikz diagram to some image format.)

Comment: @PatrickR Yeah thanks I was able to fix it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you change topology on $2$ to be discrete, and assume $f$ is restricted to be monomorphism, then this property is indeed saying that $X$ is Hausdorff. We are in the category of topological spaces, and all arrows are continuous functions. Notice also that $*$ is redundant here, as compositions of any functions that end up in $*$ are constant.

$f:2\to X$ means pick any 2 points in $X$. If exists $g:X\to A$ such that the diagram commutes, then $g(f(0)) = 0$ and $g(f(1)) = 1$.
Therefore $g^{-1}(\{0\})$ and $g^{-1}(\{1\})$ are disjoint open neighborhoods of $f(0)$ and $f(1)$ respectively. So any two different points (monomorphism assumption) have disjoint neighborhoods.

Adding another element $2 \in A$ ensures that all Hausdorff spaces have this property. If we have $x, y \in X, x\neq y$ and their open disjoint neighborhoods $G_x, G_y$ then we can define $f(0) = x, f(1) = y$ and
$$
g(a) = \begin{cases}
0 \quad : a \in G_x \\
1 \quad : a \in G_y \\
2 \quad : a \in (G_x\cup G_y)^c.
\end{cases}
$$
you can easily check that this function is continuous and diagram commutes.

Comment: The condition is that for every function $f:2\to X$ there should be a $g$ such that ...  But if $f(0)=f(1)$, there won't be such a $g$.  Something not quite right in the lifting property statement?

Comment: That's why I added monomorphism assumption, that is requirement $f(0)\neq f(1)$. If $f(0) = f(1)$ then there could not be $g$ such that original diagram commutes, if we are speaking of functions.

Comment: Right, that makes perfect sense.  So indeed the original statement by the OP was very incomplete.

Comment: @Esgeriath Ah thanks so much, I missed the assumption that f needs to be restricted to a monomorphism, from then on your explanation is clear.

Comment: @DevVorb The confusing thing is that in your question you talk about topological properties expressed in terms of lifting properties as explained in nlab.  But that is all in the category of topological spaces,  with no assumptions of injective maps only.  What they have in there does not match your diagram either, as far as I can tell??

Comment: #PatrickR Yeah so sorry, I think because my problem was that I was confused, it made my writing quite confused as well. But @Esgeriath's answer has cleared up everything. I tried to translate the nlab diagram into a familiar language, it is possible I "misstranslated" some stuff, sorry about any bother that all caused